# How to solve the equation in table so that i can get first 5 roots of the each equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*This program is to find the natural frquency of a beam with \
spring-mass connected at some arbitary location 'z'*)
Y = 2*10^11;
Iyy = 8.333*10^-6;
L = 4;
z = 0.01;
stiff = (Y*Iyy)/L^3;
k = {0.01, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
  800, 1*^3, 2*^3, 4*^3, 5*^3, 10*^3, 15*^3, 20*^3, 30*^3, 40*^3, 
  70*^3, 1*^5, 1*^6, 1*^8, 
  1*^12}(*THIS IS THE FIRST  PARAMETER REPRESENTS  STIFFNESS *)
m = {0.01, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
  800, 1*^3, 2*^3, 4*^3, 5*^3, 10*^3, 15*^3, 20*^3, 30*^3, 40*^3, 
  70*^3, 1*^5, 1*^6, 1*^8, 
  1*^12}(*THIS IS THE SECOND PARAMETER REPRESENTS  MASS*)
(*s[i_,j_]:=((m[[j]]*b^4)/(1-m[[j]]/k[[i]]*b^4))*)
(*Represents the scaling in right hand side of the differential \
equation *)
eq = (1/(2*b^3))*(((Sin[b*(1 - z)]*Sin[b*z])/
      Sin[b]) - ((Sinh[b*(1 - z)]*Sinh[b*z])/
      Sinh[b]));(*Green's function *)
eq1[i_, j_] := (1 - (((m[[j]]*b^4)/(1 - m[[j]]/k[[i]]*b^4))*eq));
sol = ArrayReshape[Table[eq1[i, j], {i, 30}, {j, 30}], {900, 1, 1}]
NSolve[sol[[1, 1]] == 0 && 0 < b < 10]
```

Now, this sol contains 900 equation how to **solve for first 5 roots** of this equation? How to solve all the equations contained in the **sol** in one single shot?

Comment: It's an eigenvalue problem, right? Then how about using `NDEigensystem` instead?

Comment: Kind off, but when I used NSolve it works manually, but when I put in the loop it didn't .  This is my try For[i = 1, i < 901, i++, S[[i]] = NSolve[sol[[i]] == 0 && 0 < b < 15]]

Comment: Try FindInstance[...,5] instead of NSolve. I am busy to to go into deep of your code which is not completely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation solving in your loop is not stuck, it's just very slow in *v11.2*. You can speed up the code by removing the removable singularity in the equation:

```
Y = 2 10^11;
Iyy = (8333/1000)/10^6;
L = 4;
z = 1/100;
stiff = (Y Iyy)/L^3;
k = {1/100, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 800, 1000, 2000, 
  4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 70000, 100000, 1000000, 100000000, 
  1000000000000}
m = {1/100, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 800, 1000, 2000, 
  4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 70000, 100000, 1000000, 100000000, 
  1000000000000}
(* Notice the following modification. *)
eq = (Sin[b (1 - z)] Sin[b z] - Sin[b] (Sinh[b (1 - z)] Sinh[b z])/Sinh[b])/(2 b^3); 
eq1[i_, j_] := Sin[b] (1 - (m[[j]] b^4)/k[[i]]) - (m[[j]] b^4) eq;

test = Table[
    b /. NSolve[eq1[i, j] == 0 && 0 < b < 20, b, WorkingPrecision -> 32], {i, 30}, {j, 
     30}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {43.0112, Null} *)
```

Notice though the roots are quite close to the singularities, they're not identical, for example:

```
test[[1, 1, 1]] - 1
(* -8.220929635875291505012540*10^-8 *)
```

BTW, it's worth mentioning that *v9* can solve these equations fast without the modification mentioned above, but it only finds 6252 roots, while *v11.2* finds 6256.

Comment: ok, then from where the actual roots start then?, If it is throwing b->1 , there should be a zero cross over at 1 right?

Comment: @vijay I have to retract my words, the roots are not spurious. Check my edit.

Comment: ok, I will check, thanks for the help.